# Skip datavalidation in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Is it possible to skip validation in mongodb using pymongo?

I want to run below query from pymongo :

```
db.getMongo()._skipValidation = true
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have schema validation configured in MongoDB, you can nevertheless bypass validation when you insert or update documents with the `bypass_document_validation` option:

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one

Comment: I am trying to figure out when I would want bypass_document_validation=True. Is it when I want to increase performance and I am sure I will always insert a valid json document?